# How define in Ansible a version of package to install

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, ansible

I am using Ansible and I want to define the version of the package in main.yml task. I am trying to install postgresql-9.1 version:

```
---
- name: Copy source list
  copy: src=sources.list dest=/etc/apt/sources.list

- name: Update apt
  shell: apt-get update

- name: Install the version 9.1 of postgresql
  sudo: True
  apt: name=postgresql=9.1  state=present

- name: Ensure postgresql is << Started >>
  sudo: yes
  sudo_user: postgres
  service: name=postgresql state=started
```

But I got this error:

```
PLAY [database] *************************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [slave1]

TASK: [postgresql | Copy source list] ***************************************** 
ok: [slave1]

TASK: [postgresql | Update apt] *********************************************** 
changed: [slave1]

TASK: [postgresql | Install the version 9.1 of postgresql] ******************** 
failed: [slave1] => {"failed": true}
stderr: E: Version '9.1' for 'postgresql' was not found

stdout: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...

msg: 'apt-get install 'postgresql=9.1' ' failed: E: Version '9.1' for 'postgresql' was not found


FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
           to retry, use: --limit @/home/robe/site.retry

slave1                     : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Then, How do I declare the package version to install?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `apt` module correctly to specify a version. This would also fail at the commandline with `apt-get install postgresql-9.1`. You haven't shown what's in your `sources.list`, but he's a way to do it:

```
- apt_key: id=ACCC4CF8 url=https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc state=present
- apt_repository: repo='deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main' update_cache=yes state=present
- name: Install the version 9.1 of postgresql
  apt: name=postgresql=9.1  state=present
```

Comment: Giving me: ``failed: [default] => {"cmd": "apt-key add -", "failed": true, "rc": 2}``, any idea why that is?, thanks

Comment: @AlfonsoPérez are you using those exact four lines? If not, post your tasks.

Comment: yes, that specific issue was resolved adding `sudo: yes`, so now I have: `- apt_key: id=ACCC4CF8 url=https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc state=present
  sudo: yes

- apt_repository: repo='deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main' update_cache=yes state=present
  sudo: yes

- name: Install the version 9.1 of postgresql
  sudo: yes
  apt: name=postgresql=9.1  state=present`

but getting: `msg: '/usr/bin/apt-get -y -o "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef" -o "Dpkg::Options::[...] 1'' failed: E: Version '9.1' for 'postgresql' was not found`